# In Scala, what is the difference between Any and Object?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following java method

```
protected void onEvent(Object obj) {

    }
```

The Scala compiler accepts

```
protected override def onEvent(event: Any)
```

and

```
protected override def onEvent(event: Object)
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is an [article](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128) on scala-lang with great diagram (I even put it on the wall). And  also need to be mentioned:

> If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, then scala.AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object.

Comment: Correct. Note that `AnyRef` is not `Any`, but a subclass. `Any` has subclass `AnyVal` also.

Comment: @Ernest Yes. The chart shows it very clear. Don't understand. Is there something I missed?

Comment: no, you didn't miss anything; I just wanted to clarify for people who didn't follow the link.

Answer (score 26):

`Any` includes things that are not `Object`s in Java; it includes primitive types and also `Nothing`. `Object` is the same class as in Java, so it definitely excludes primitives.

Comment: So if you are attempting to a Java method that uses Object, does Any get you into trouble if you pass in a primitive or is it implicitly converted?

Comment: @James i tried `def met(a: java.lang.Object) = {}; val i = 10; met(i)` and here's the output from compiler: *error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef* http://stackoverflow.com/a/26550576/4541480, it worked with `val i: java.lang.Integer = 10` (not with default `val i: Int = 10`