# Result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef

Tags: scala

Let

```
def h(a: AnyRef*) = a.mkString(",")
h: (a: AnyRef*)String
```

and so

```
h("1","2")
res: String = 1,2
```

However, `h(1,2)`

```
error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
              h(1,2)
                ^
error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
              h(1,2)
                  ^
```

This is at least in Scala 2.11.1 and 2.11.1.
To ask on a workaround.

Comment: The scala repl on scala 2.10.X gives back a much more meaningful response: `error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: AnyRef
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`.
              h(1,2)
`

Comment: By the way, you can reproduce the problem with `val x: AnyRef = 42`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can reproduce the issue simply with:

```
val x: AnyRef = 42
```

Here's the relevant [pull request on github](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2625) that introduced the change

The rationale is that for security reasons some implicit conversions are explicitly disabled, namely when the conversion goes from `T` to `U` is disabled if:

```
T <: Null
```

or

```
AnyRef <: U
```

In your specific case, this means that an `Int` (which is not an `AnyRef`) will never be converted to `AnyRef`.

If you need to accept both `Int` and `String`, you can consider accepting `Any` instead. Since every scala object inherits from `Any`, there's no implicit conversion needed.

```
def h(a: Any*) = a.mkString(",")
```

Comment: what if h is a java function like h(ArrayList<Object> x)?

Answer (score 36):

The reason is that the numeric type of the literals 1 and 2 is `Int` which extends `AnyVal` which, in turn, extends `Any`. On the other hand `String` extends `AnyRef` which, in turn, extends `Any`. So as you can see `AnyVal` (`Int`'s parent) does not extend `AnyRef`. You can solve this in one of two ways.

The first one is changing the type from `AnyRef` to `Any` as described by Nate.

The second one is using a type ascription for the literals 1 and 2 so that they are considered of type `java.lang.Integer` which extends `java.lang.Object`. Note also that `AnyRef` is just an alias for `java.lang.Object`. So, using your definition the following should work:

```
scala> h(1: java.lang.Integer, 2: java.lang.Integer)
res2: String = 1,2
```

More info on [Scala Hierarchy](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html)

Answer (score 7):

Cast your variable to `AnyRef` by doing something like this:

```
h(1.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], 2.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

Why?

In scala not everything extends `Object` (aka `AnyRef`) in the way that it would in java. Specifically primitives extend `AnyVal`, so if your function requires an `AnyRef` you'll need to cast / convert / restrict your scala variables.

There's a good discussion here: [What are the relationships between Any, AnyVal, AnyRef, Object and how do they map when used in Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-m)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you want to use `AnyRef` here. I think you want `Any`.

```
scala> def h(a: Any*) = a.mkString(",")
h: (a: Any*)String

scala> h(1,2)
res0: String = 1,2
```

The reason is that the numeric value `5` is an Int, but `AnyRef` is java's `Object` equivalence. So to invoke that method it would need to be a java.util.Integer.