# Automated mapping and "implicit conversion must be more specific then Any Ref" error

Tags: scala

Based on the [activator-akka-cassandra](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-cassandra) example I'm creating my own app which will save data into cassandra.

I defind a data model as follows

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)
object Location {
  implicit def toLocation(lat: Double, long: Double) = Location(lat, long)
}

case class LocationWithTime(location: Location, time: Long)
object LocationWithTime {
  implicit def toLocationWithTime(location: Location, time: Long) = LocationWithTime(location, time)
}

case class Ping(pingUuid: String, senPhoneNumber: String, recPhoneNumber: Set[String], locationWithTime: LocationWithTime)
object Ping {
  implicit val LocationFormat = Json.format[Location]
  implicit val LocationWithTimeFormat = Json.format[LocationWithTime]
  implicit val PingFormat = Json.format[Ping]
}
```

Unfortunately the code which is supposed to save the data:

```
def insertPing(ping: Ping): Unit =
    session.executeAsync(insertPing.bind(ping.pingUuid, ping.senPhoneNumber, ping.recPhoneNumber,
      ping.locationWithTime.location.lat, ping.locationWithTime.location.long, ping.locationWithTime.time))
```

does not not compile and return the error

```
Error:(24, 38) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
      ping.locationWithTime.location.lat, ping.locationWithTime.location.long, ping.locationWithTime.time))
                                 ^
```

The case classes in the [example data model](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-cassandra/blob/master/src/main/scala/domain/tweet.scala) extend AnyVal. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546299/result-type-of-an-implicit-conversion-must-be-more-specific-than-anyref) I would guess that something similar would do the trick in my case too, but I can't do that because ValueClasses can have only one parameter.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Is your prepared statement also called `insertPing`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with Cassandra, I think your problem is that `bind` takes Java `Object`s (i.e. `AnyRef`s) and `lat`, is a `scala.Double` (i.e. a Java `double`), which is not an `AnyRef`.

You can make it such by wrapping your `scala.Double`s in `java.lang.Double`.

```
insertPing.bind(ping.pingUuid, ping.senPhoneNumber, ping.recPhoneNumber, new java.lang.Double(ping.locationWithTime.location.lat), new java.lang.Double(ping.locationWithTime.location.long), ping.locationWithTime.time)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, however you forgot a new before java.lang.Double. So it should be `session.executeAsync(insertPing.bind(ping.pingUuid, ping.senPhoneNumber, ping.recPhoneNumber,
      new java.lang.Double(ping.locationWithTime.location.lat), new java.lang.Double(ping.locationWithTime.location.long),
      new java.lang.Long(ping.locationWithTime.time)))`

Comment: This is what I get for not checking this with a compiler. Editing the answer now.