# Scala: execute functions one by one and passing parameters between them

Tags: scala

I have a class with an **unknown** number of functions:

```
class processors {
  def p1(s: String): String = {
    //code
  }
  def p2(s: String): String = {
    //code
  }
  def p3(s: String): String = {
    //code
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to run all the function one by one in the order they are written (p1 -> p2 -> p3 -> ...). Also, I would like to pass the initial string to `p1`, which will pass the result as the argument for `p2` and do on. Is there a simple way to do that?

**EDIT:**

What I have so far:

At the moment I have a hard-coded sequence:

```
val processors = Seq(p1 _, p2 _, p3 _).reduce(_ andThen _)
processors(some_string)
```

I'd like to avoid the hard-coding, basically..

Comment: Do you control the class? Do you know how many methods it has? If you don't (as you say *unknown* in your question), how exactly do you invoke them now?

Comment: If you don't return a processor in each function, I doubt you can call the function is this wait p1 -> p2 -> p3. You should explain in a better way the current question. You can probably define something like: def p1(s:String):processor = {} def p2(s:processor): processor{} def p3(s:processor):processor{} you can add a value corresponding to the current String value every time processor is changed the corretValue can be changed.

Comment: `def run(s: String): String = p3(p2(p1(s))) // jokes on you :)` If you don't know the number of steps just use reflection API to get all methods, throw them into a list and call one by one recursively passing the String as accumulator.

Comment: I've edited the post, showing what I use so far. I'd like refrain from using `var`s, as this will run on Spark..

Comment: When you say "hard to avoid hard-coding", do you mean you don't want to explicitly mention each new added method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : exactly

Comment: What about macro annotation for `processors` class, that will find all `pN-like` methods in compile-time and generate additional combined method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection can help here. this example is for single param integer argument, but it can be extended to multiple arguments but it gets bit tricky dealing with types. Argument types can be queried from the class.

```
class A {
  def f(x: Int): Int = 2 * x
  def g(x: Int): Int = x * x
}

val clazz = classOf[A]

clazz.getDeclaredMethods.filter(! _.getName.contains("$"))
.map(x => {a: Integer => x.invoke(new A(), a: Integer).asInstanceOf[Integer] })
.reduce(_ andThen _)(new Integer(1))
```

For your case just replace `Int` with `String`

*To maintain the order of execution of the functions in the class*

*try to put number in the function name and then order them by parsing string obtained from getName method*

Comment: That's exactly what I said I do not want to do

Comment: @shakedzy . Edited the answer. hope this helps you.

Comment: Here three ways:
1) hard code
2) java or scala reflection
3) macro annotation: `@procontainer class processors`. see <http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations>

Comment: @shakedzy Result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546299/result-type-of-an-implicit-conversion-must-be-more-specific-than-anyref

Comment: @pamu I would appreciate if you could edit your answer, so the code will compile. I don't understand what you're trying to point at

Comment: @shakedzy  edited the answer with working solution. Please tell me if this is useful to you

Comment: @pamu I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`, probably from the `andThen` part

Comment: @pamu fixed it. just adding `clazz.getDeclaredMethods.filter(! _.getName.contains("$"))` in order to remove Scala created methods. Thanks!

Comment: @pamu It doesn't keep an order. I can sometimes be `p1 -> p2 -> p3` and another `p2 -> p3 -> p1`.. The order is important in my case

Comment: @shakedzy try to put number in the function name and then order them by parsing string obtained from `getName` method.